# How do I highlight incorrectly matching keywords in a two column list that should match in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I feel like this is complicated to explain so please ask clarifying questions if you need to. I have a list of keywords, with a list of authors in the next column. Based on two other lists, I need to highlight any author names that do not match the keyword. Please see screenshots below for the current spreadsheet and the desired output. The actual keyword and author list I will end up working with will be much longer than this, approximately 13,000 lines. Here is a testing sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_JppmT-KoUGIadm3uvgYaoGhRsnTn10kShRD6Ia3Dpk/edit#gid=0

[image: Current output]

[image: Desired output]

Comment: Could you explain more how it ended up that Author 13 is considered an incorrect author based on what requirement?

Comment: @CenturyTuna You're absolutely right, I used a valid answer for my "incorrect" answer example. Thank you for pointing that out, going to edit it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those additional columns, you can use this formula that nests different REDUCE functions:

```
=QUERY(REDUCE({"Keyword","Author"},FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>""),LAMBDA(a,b,{a;REDUCE({"",""},FILTER(E2:E,D2:D=b),LAMBDA(c,d,{c;REDUCE({"",""},FILTER(H2:H,G2:G=d),LAMBDA(e,f,{e;b,f}))}) )}) ),"WHERE Col1 is not null")
```

[image]

For conditional formatting, it checks with MATCH if it is found inside the filtered values of K column according with J column:

```
=ISNA(MATCH(B2,FILTER(K:K,J:J=A2),0))*(B2<>"")
```

[image]